# Generate magazine flatplan with constraints

Tags: python, constraints, combinations, permutation, generative

I'm working on a magazine. We are working with multiple types of papers (short articles, long articles, portfolio, ads, etc.) that together make 128 pages in total. I'm looking for a way to generate ordering proposals for those articles (flatplan). We have constraints such as, for eg.:

- editorial should be first (2 pages)
- table of content should appear next
- article is n pages, and should start on a left page
- an ad should be on a right page
- two investigation paper shouldn't be adjacent
- etc.

Is there a way to generate flatplan proposals based on those constraints?

My language of choice is Python, but I'm open to any suggestion!

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is very vague. Some of the constrains are trivial. If you want the editorial at the beginning, then put it at the beginning. Is your question what selection of papers to put in the magazine so the total number of pages is <=128?  So you have a list of n papers with pages [20,11,45,3,....]  and you want a combination of papers that does not exceed 128 pages? You need something to maximize, otherwise put just one paper. Do you want to maximize number of papers? This will make the shorter papers selected, which will impact the quality of the magazine. So define first your targets

Comment: Hi, I edited a bit the question. I hope it addresses some of your comments. Thanks